# Creating a Choropleth map with US county level data

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, ggmap, choropleth

I'm trying to produce a choropleth map of county level data on COVID-19 infections using R.  I'm a relative newbie to R so....

I've done some fairly basic stuff with ggmap to plot spatial data, but never anything quite like this.  Typically I just have points of interest that I need to overlay on a map, so I can use geom_point and their lat/lon.  In this case I need to construct the underlying map and then fill regions and I'm struggling with doing that in the ggplot world.

I've followed some online examples I've found to get as far as this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(broom)
library(geojsonio)

#get a county level map geoJSON file
counties <- geojson_read("https://eric.clst.org/assets/wiki/uploads/Stuff/gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.json", what = "sp")

#filter our alaska and Hawaii
lower48 <- counties[(counties@data$STATE != "02" & counties@data$STATE != "15") ,]

#turn it into a dataframe for ggmap
new_counties <- tidy(lower48)

# Plot it
print(ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = new_counties, aes( x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill="#69b3a2", color="white") +
  theme_void() +
  coord_map())
```

Which produces this plot:

[image]

So far so good.  But my new_counties dataframe now looks like this:

```
head(new_counties)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
   long   lat order hole  piece group id  
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <lgl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 -85.4  33.9     1 FALSE 1     0.1   0    
2 -85.4  33.9     2 FALSE 1     0.1   0    
3 -85.4  33.9     3 FALSE 1     0.1   0    
4 -85.4  33.9     4 FALSE 1     0.1   0    
5 -85.4  33.9     5 FALSE 1     0.1   0    
6 -85.4  33.8     6 FALSE 1     0.1   0
```

So I've lost anything that I might be able to tie back to my county level data on infections.

My data has a 5-digit FIPS code for each county.  First two digits are the state and last three are the county.  My geoJSON file has a much more detailed FIPS code.  I tried grabbing just the first 5 and creating my own data element I could map back to

```
library(ggplot2)
library(broom)
library(geojsonio)

#get a county level map geoJSON file
counties <- geojson_read("https://eric.clst.org/assets/wiki/uploads/Stuff/gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.json", what = "sp")

#filter our alaska and Hawaii
lower48 <- counties[(counties@data$STATE != "02" & counties@data$STATE != "15") ,]

#add my own FIPS code
lower48@data$myFIPS <- substr(as.character(lower48@data$GEO_ID),1,5)  

#turn it into a dataframe for ggmap
new_counties <- tidy(lower48, region = "myFIPS")


# Plot it
print(ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = new_counties, aes( x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill="#69b3a2", color="white") +
  theme_void() +
  coord_map())
```

But that produces this plot

[image]

And I have to say I'm not quite familiar enough with broom::tidy to know exactly why.
I also notice as I type this that I need to filter out Puerto Rico!

If anybody can point me back in a useful direction....I'm not wedded to the current approach, though I would like to stick to ggplot2 or ggmap.  My boss eventually wants me to overlay certain features.  Ultimately the goal is to follow the example [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/315157_73b802e0532c4ea3839f98afc0378ca1.html#choropleth_maps) and produce an animated map showing data over time, but I'm obviously a long way from that.

Comment: use `sf::st_read()` to read the geojson, so you get it as an `sf` object. Then use `ggplot2::geom_sf()` to plot it. - `sf` is the successor to `sp`, so I would recommend anyone to move away from `sp`.

Comment: where an `sf` object **is** already a data.frame. So all standard filtering and subsetting operations 'just work'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's many ways to do this, but the concept is basically the same: Find a map containing country level FIPS codes and use them to link with a data source, also containing the same FIPS codes as well as the variable for plotting (here the number of covid-19 cases per day).

```
#devtools::install_github("UrbanInstitute/urbnmapr")
library(urbnmapr) # For map
library(ggplot2)  # For map
library(dplyr)    # For summarizing
library(tidyr)    # For reshaping
library(stringr)  # For padding leading zeros
```

---

```
# Get COVID cases, available from:
url <- "https://static.usafacts.org/public/data/covid-19/covid_confirmed_usafacts.csv
             ?_ga=2.162130428.136323622.1585096338-408005114.1585096338"

COV <- read.csv(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(COV)[1] <- "countyFIPS"  # Fix the name of first column. Why!?
```

The data are stored in wide format with daily cases per county spread across columns. This needs to be gathered before merging with the map. The dates need to be converted to proper dates. The FIPS codes are stored as integers, so these need to be converted to a character with leading 0s in order to merge with the map data. I use the **urbnmap** package for the map data.

```
Covid <- pivot_longer(COV, cols=starts_with("X"), 
                     values_to="cases",
                     names_to=c("X","date_infected"),
                     names_sep="X") %>%                
  mutate(date_infected = as.Date(date_infected, format="%m.%d.%Y"),
         countyFIPS = str_pad(as.character(countyFIPS), 5, pad="0"))

# Obtain map data for counties (to link with covid data) and states (for showing borders)
states_sf <- get_urbn_map(map = "states", sf = TRUE)
counties_sf <- get_urbn_map(map = "counties", sf = TRUE)

# Merge county map with total cases of cov
counties_cov <- inner_join(counties_sf, group_by(Covid, countyFIPS) %>%
       summarise(cases=sum(cases)), by=c("county_fips"="countyFIPS"))

counties_cov %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = cases), color = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = states_sf, fill = NA, color = "black", size = 0.25) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA) +   
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "Cases", trans = "log", low='pink', high='navyblue', 
                      na.value="white", breaks=c(1, max(counties_cov$cases))) +
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position="bottom", panel.border = element_blank())
```

---

[image]

---

For animation, you can use the **gganimate** package and transition through the days. The commands are similar to above except that the covid data should not be summarized.

```
library(gganimate)

counties_cov <- inner_join(counties_sf, Covid, by=c("county_fips"="countyFIPS"))

p <- ggplot(counties_cov) + ... # as above

p <- p + transition_time(date_infected) +
  labs(title = 'Date: {frame_time}')

animate(p, end_pause=30)
```

---

[image]

Comment: That is awesome...I'd made some progress using the `choroplethr` package, but this puts  me to shame.  I'll study this...

Comment: For some reason it didn't like the countyFIPS column name it read from the URL and stuck the i umlaut (or whatever you call it) on there, so I manually removed that.  Do you know what transformation is required to overlay some lat/lon geom_points on the map?  As is, they all just wind up in South Dakota with a warning `Transformation introduced infinite values in discrete y-axis`.  I ran into that with another package I tried and it had to do with the projection the map was using.  That package provided a transform() function to make lat/lon's plottable...

Comment: Disregard...figured it out using the `usmap_transform` function from the `usmap` package

Comment: New issue though, when I attempt to animate I get `Error: time data must either be integer, numeric, POSIXct, Date, difftime, orhms
In addition: Warning message:
In min(cl[cl != 0]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf` . date_infected entries look like `1.22.2020` do I need to use `as.date()` or `strptime()` or similar to transform these?

Comment: That did it.... `as.date()` and it's all good.  One last wrinkle to figure out..thanks again

Comment: Upon further review, you had already as.date'd...just to `infected` so I just need to change `transition_time(date_infected)` to `transition_time(infected)`.  Do you know why some of the counties start out as gray and others white?  I believe in both cases the value is 0.  I'd like to get rid of the starting grays if possible...

Comment: I fixed that small bug about date_infected. Concerning the grey counties, those have cases on at least one day during the whole period, while white counties have no cases at any time. I thought it was a nice "feature", but there should be a way to disable that. ...

Comment: Oh okay....that's cool then.  I thought ít was just inconsistent with 0s for some reason....as long as I can explain that.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: If you don't like the grey, you can add na.values="white" or na.values="transparent" in the scale_fill_gradient function.

Comment: I updated packages and there are no longer .png files in the working directory, so gifski has nothing to encode.  I had been using `print(p + transition_time(infected) + labs(title='COVID-19 Cases: {frame_time}'))` in my script and it was fine...any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: I actually went ahead and posted a new question about itt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60893598/why-are-ggplot-output-files-no-longer-appearing)